# Javascript jquery add active class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, class

I'm trying to add `active` class to my unordered list using jQuery. I've tried many solutions on Stackoverflow and it doesn't seem to work. I want to make the `active` class color red. Can someone tell me why it is not working?

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm also getting this error in my browser console:

```
 error: $("li").click() is not a valid function
```

Comment: works fine ... what error do you see in your browser console and what's your css for class active?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me

Comment: Did you want to add the colour to your anchor text instead? You can see from the updated snippet that only the list item is being updated. Anchors should be treated differently because they have to be styled differently.

Comment: Are you expecting the `<a>link</a>` text to also change?

Comment: `a` elements don't inherit the parent color style by default. Add `.active a {color: inherit;}` rule to the stylesheet to make `a` to inherit the parent style. (`inherit` or `red`, using the former, you don't need to gain attention to this particular rule, if you want to change the color later.)

Comment: As soon as i retry in visual studio code it returns an error. Maybe i cant use javascript inline with html.

Comment: Obvious question: what's the error?

Comment: You can use js in an html file, just make sure it has `<script>` tags around it.  They're not needed in the snippet "javascript" panel as SO handles it.  Your original code had a `<script>` tag fine.

Comment: The error says that $("li").click(function() is not a valid function

Comment: Assuming it's saying that 'click' is not a function then it means that the `$` variable is not a reference to jQuery, and the libraries you're adding to the page need to be checked.

Comment: the error exactly says:

> error: $("li").click(function() is not a valid function

Comment: I'm more confused since i added a unrelated comment behind the function and now it seems to work. When i delete only the comment it fails at the function again. I dont know how but thats life now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code works well. But I see that you said you are getting an error message `error: $("li").click(function() is not a valid function`. We usually get this error message when load our custom JS code that contains jQuery functions before loading the main jQuery script to the document

So to solve it put the jQuery library code inside the HTML `<head></head>` tag

```css
.active { color: red; }
.active a { color: red; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Your custom script here -->
    <script>
      $("li").click(function() {
        $("li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I even could delete the comment after this. 
I still dont know how the comment solved it however i enjoy the help i received.

Comment: I saw that you commented that you were getting that error in your question and from the error message I become sure that it is the jquery load problem :)